# Applet with buttons

Tags: java, button, applet

I have programmed up an applet to have two checkers move back and forth by themselves in opposite directions . How could I add a button that moves them back and forth with a click instead of automatically. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*; 

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;

public class Checkers extends java.applet.Applet implements Runnable {

  Thread runner;
  int x1pos;
  int x2pos;
  Image offscreenImg;
  Graphics offscreenG;
  private Button move;

  public void init() 
  {
    offscreenImg = createImage(this.size().width, this.size().height);
    offscreenG = offscreenImg.getGraphics();
  }



  public void start()
   {
    if (runner == null); {
      runner = new Thread(this);
      runner.start();
    }
  }

  public void stop()
   {
    if (runner != null) {
      runner.stop();
      runner = null;
    }
  }

  public void run() 
  {
    while (true) {
      for (x1pos = 5, x2pos = 105; x1pos <= 105 && x2pos >= 5; x1pos+=4, x2pos -=4)
       {
        repaint ();
        try { Thread.sleep(100); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
       }
     x1pos = 5;
     x2pos = 105;
    }
  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
     paint(g);
  }


  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Draw background onto the buffer area
    offscreenG.setColor(Color.black);
    offscreenG.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
    offscreenG.setColor(Color.blue);
    offscreenG.fillRect(100,0,100,100);
    offscreenG.setColor(Color.blue);
    offscreenG.fillRect(0,100,100,100);
    offscreenG.setColor(Color.black);
    offscreenG.fillRect(100,100,100,100);

    // Draw checker
    offscreenG.setColor(Color.red);
    offscreenG.fillOval(x1pos,5,90,90);
    offscreenG.setColor(Color.green);
    offscreenG.fillOval(x2pos,105,90,90);


    // Now, transfer the entire buffer onto the screen
    g.drawImage(offscreenImg,0,0,this);
  }
  public void destroy() {
     offscreenG.dispose();
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help